# RxJava dependend method calls with async for loop

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I have multiple dependend calls that I would like to solve with RxJava:

1. **Get all entities** that have a file that is not yet uploaded
2. **Upload** the file to the server
3. **Update** the entity with the received url
4. **Upload** the entity to the server

I tried different approaches but coulden't make it work. I can't get my head around on how to wait until the file upload has been finished. Here is my current code:

```
Observable.fromIterable(repository.getFileNotUploaded()) // Returns a list of all entities that should be uploaded to the server
    .flatMap(entity ->
            restService.uploadFile(new File(directory.getPath(), entity.getLocalPath()))
                    .subscribe(fileUrl -> {
                        entity.setFileUrl(fileUrl);
                        repository.update(entity);
                    }));
// TODO: Wait until all files have been uploaded and the entities have been stored
// locally. Then upload the list of all entities.
```

Rest call:

```
public Observable<String> uploadFile(File file) {

    return Observable.create(emitter -> {
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                commClient.sendFileRequest(URL, file,
                        response -> {
                        // ...
                        if(success){
                                emitter.onNext(new String(response.data));
                        }

                            emitter.onComplete();
                        }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Also I read that calling subscribe inside a flat map is an anti pattern. How can I cascade my method calls? Should I use the range method and return the current positoin of my iteration?

---

**Edit - Working solution thanks to Emanuel S**

The solution of Emanuel S works. I had also to change my rest service. This service must return an `Observable<Entity>` and not an `Observable<String>`. Also note that one should not mix up AsyncTask and Rx.

```
public Observable<Entity> uploadFile(File file, Entity entity) {
//...
entity.setFileUrl(fileUrl);
emitter.onNext(entity);
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If repository.getFileNotUploaded() is an ArrayList/Collection you should create your Observable with just and iterate after.

This may work (untested, wrote it without IDE) and upload all your entites in a bunch.

As akarnokd wrote, you dont need to use `just` and `flatmapIterable`, since you can just use `fromIterable`.

```
Observable.just(repository.getFileNotUploaded()).flatMapIterable ( files -> file)
// OR 
Observable.flatmapIterable(repository.getFileNotUploaded())

.flatMap(entity -> rs.uploadFile(new File(yourPath, entity.getLocalPath())) // for each file not uploaded run another observable and return it
.map(entity -> { entity.setFieldUrl(fileUrl); return entity; }) // modify the entity and return it
.toList() // get it back to List<String> with your entities
.flatMap(entityList -> uploadEntityObservable(entityList))
.subscribe( 
    success -> Log.d("Success", "All entities and files uploaded"), 
    error -> Log.e("Error", "error happened somewhere")
);
```

If you want to upload each modified entity with a single call you may want to replace

```
.toList() // get it back to List<String> with your entities
.flatMap(entityList -> uploadEntityObservable(entityList ))
```

with

```
.flatMapIterable( singleEntity -> uploadSingleEntity(singleEntity))
```

And dont mix asyntask with RxJava. You dont need AsyncTask if you have RXJava.

Take care: If you stream your Data and if your repository Observable emit data you need to use

```
repository.getFileNotUploaded() // Observable<Whatever> emit data in a stream.
.flatMapIterable ( files -> file) ...
```

Comment: `repository.getFileNotUploaded` returns a `List<Entity>`. If I use `Observable.just` I get the whole list (entities) and not just one entity inside the flatMap and map.

Comment: Your'r right, tested and updated. Usually i stream my data (Kotlin). Anyway, should work now.

Comment: It's up to him. Ive learned: first create an Observable with the values, then flattern it. Can't remember why, but i'm sure there's a difference. Oh, and it's cool with Kotlin. list.toObservable() :P. Ah, i remember. Because usually i split Observables for readability and/or stream them.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! I have a problem with with the `.map` part. The `entity` here is a string and not an object. Do I have a problem in my rest request, because I return there a string?

Comment: Make sure that your Observable (better Single) is emitting the proper type you want to use. map{} uses the type which was used by the observable in the flatmap. In your case rs.uploadFile() must return a string. Just update your code and i'll try to figure out whats wrong. Try to avoid Lambdas for testing and remove them after you found the issue.

Comment: My `rs.uploadFile()` returns an `Observable<String>`. I don't see where the `entety` in the map comes from. Or if I change it, where I get the ´fileUrl` String? Can you provide the sample code, you used for the `rs.uploadFile()`

Comment: The returnValue of your uploadFile must be an Entity. you map/get the return Value and transform it to another value/type

Comment: Thank you so much. I will also make some changes based on your suggestions.

Comment: No problem ;-) Glad to help you.